# The radical of an ideal is principal

Tags: linear-algebra, radicals, unique-factorization-domains

Let $F$ be a unique factorization domain and $f \in F$. Show that the radical of the ideal generated by $f$ is principal, i.e. $\sqrt{(f)} = (g)$.

Since $F$ is a unique factorization domain we can write an unique decomposition of $f$, i.e. write $f = \prod_{i} p_i^{n_i}$. If we choose $h \in \sqrt{(f)}$, then by definition of the radical, there exists $m \in N^*$ such that $h^m \in (f)$.
Thus we can write $h^m = k f = k \prod_{i} p_i^{n_i}$. Since $h \in F$, we can again decompose $h$ into irreducible elements, i.e. $h = \prod_{j} s_j$.

Thus we have,
$\prod_{j} s_j^m = k \prod_{i} p_i^{n_i}$.

How to proceed now?

Answer (score 2):

Note that you have shown that $p_i \mid h^m$ for all $i$ and hence, $p_i \mid h$ for all $i$. (Why?)

Using that, you can see that $h \in \left(\prod_ip_i\right).$ Thus, $\sqrt{(f)} \subset \left(\prod_ip_i\right)$. Can you show the other inclusion as well?

---

To continue your approach, you could further decompose each $s_j$ as a product of primes and conclude that each $p_i$ divides some $s_j$ and deduce the same as above.

Comment: $p_i \vert h^m \Rightarrow p_i \vert h$ because of Euclid's lemma (the $p_i$ are primes)?

Comment: For the other inclusion I want to show that for $h \in \left( \prod_i p_i \right)$ there exists $m \in \mathbb{N}^*$ such that $h^m \in \left(\prod_{i} p_i^{n_i}\right) = (f)$. Then we have shown that $h \in \sqrt{(f)}$. But I don't know how exactly to show this.

Comment: @earth: Well, that implication is because of the _definition_ of a prime in the ring-theoretic setting. Namely, $p \mid ab \implies p \mid a \text{ or } p \mid b$. For the other inclusion, note that it suffices to show that $\prod_i p_i \in \sqrt{(f)}$. (Why?) Is there a certain large enough of the product that you think will work?